# Swagger documentation to show response details of abstract classs

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, springfox, swagger-3.0

I have a Spring Boot application with a REST API that returns the following object:

```java
public class Response {
    private DTO data;
    private Error error;
}
```

`DTO` is an abstract class for all DTOs:

```java
public abstract class DTO { }
```

The subclass:

```java
public class CountryDTO extends DTO {
  private Long id;
  private String code;
  private String name;
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I check the API documentation in Swagger UI, it does not show the details of the real DTO that I send as part of the response. Instead, Swagger UI just shows:

```json
{
  "data": {},
  "error": {
    "message": "string"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to tell Swagger UI to show the correct the correct DTO JSON that I will return as part of this API?

Comment: Can you post the DTO class with the relevant annotations? What language and library do you use (e.g. Java+Springfox, Java+Springdoc, .NET+Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, etc.)?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  

spring boot application

and the dto class:


public abstract class DTO {

}

while the subclass
```
public class CountryDTO extends DTO{

    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
}
```